# Why doesn't getElementsByTagName work in this logic?

Tags: javascript, html-table, getelementsbytagname

Just testing this out, trying to insert a table into the body tag but I can only do it with getElementById. I also tried inserting the script code at the bottom, but that doesn't work either.

```
<html>

<head>
        <title>Exam Test Trial</title>
        <script>
        var table;
            var books = {1234: "Programming for Dummies", 5667: "Ethical Hacking", 88889: "Networks", 10000: "Firmware Code"};

                function createTable(){
                table = "<table border= '1'>";

                table += "<tr>";

                for(var isbn in books){
                    table += "<th>";
                    table += isbn;
                    table += "</th>";
                }

                table += "</tr>";
                table += "</table>";


                //var x = document.getElementById("exam").innerHTML = table;

                var y;
            }


        </script>
</head>

<body id="exam">
    <script>
        createTable();
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML = table;
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList and not an individual Node. That's why you don't access `innerHTML` for the `body` element.

Comment: Why not simply `document.body.innerHTML`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName("body")` returns an array-like structure. Did you mean `getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`, perhaps?

Comment: @Havvy Got a reference to that first one? As far as I can tell, it doesn't exist

Comment: @Havvy Is there `getElementByTagName`? I'm not sure that exists.

Comment: This is the proper answer, he was not aware it was an array.

Comment: @GwiddleWorker—[*getElementsByTagName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) doesn't return an Array, it returns a [*NodeList*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177). ;-)